# Why I can't update form successfully?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a project where the User model is created by device gem, and 3 roles, which are children of the User model. Every role has one profile. And I want to edit and then update every profile, but can't, instead of redirecting to update action, it shows that

> The action 'create' could not be found for UserProfilesController

Here is my UserProfiles controller

```
class UserProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_profile, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  def edit
    @profile = current_user.profile
  end

  def update
    @profile = current_user.profile
    @profile.update(profile_params)
  end

  private

  def load_profile
    @profile = current_user.profile || current_user.build_profile
  end

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :description, :first_name, :last_name, :nickname,
                                    :how_heard, :birthday, :experience_years)
  end
end
```

Nutritionist form:

```
    = simple_form_for @profile do |f|
    = f.input :first_name
    = f.input :last_name
    = f.input :work
    = f.input :experience_years
    = f.input :how_heard
    = f.input :birthday, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 90,
                        end_year: Date.today.year,
                        order: [:day, :month, :year]
    = f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Client form:

```
  = simple_form_for @profile do |f|
      = f.input :first_name
      = f.input :last_name
      = f.input :nickname
      = f.input :how_heard
      = f.input :birthday, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 90,
                          end_year: Date.today.year,
                          order: [:day, :month, :year]
      = f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Administrator form:

```
= simple_form_for @profile do |f|
      = f.input :first_name
      = f.input :last_name
      = f.input :nickname
      = f.input :how_heard
      = f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Edit view:

```
    %h2 Edit page
- if current_user.instance_of?(Client)
  = render partial: "form_for_client", locals: { profile: @profile }
- elsif current_user.instance_of?(Nutritionist)
  = render partial: "form_for_nutritionist", locals: { profile: @profile }
- else
  = render partial: "form_for_administrator", locals: { profile: @profile }
```

And route:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'user_registrations' }
resource :user_profiles
```

Also here is some part of source html code:

```
<form class="simple_form new_nutritionist_profile" id="new_nutritionist_profile" novalidate="novalidate" action="/user_profiles" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="JUBFG8QwUfsvw55GqFp6tR1dYGrcqflsY+duGt2Y65aDTsKqlINAllD7JP+hqrwRR3otILAhkdN0lH2tYZGlvw==" /><div class="form-group string optional nutritionist_profile_first_name"><label class="form-control-label string optional" for="nutritionist_profile_first_name">First name</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="nutritionist_profile[first_name]" id="nutritionist_profile_first_name" /></div>
<div class="form-group string optional nutritionist_profile_last_name"><label class="form-control-label string optional" for="nutritionist_profile_last_name">Last name</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="nutritionist_profile[last_name]" id="nutritionist_profile_last_name" /></div>
<div class="form-group string optional nutritionist_profile_work"><label class="form-control-label string optional" for="nutritionist_profile_work">Work</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="nutritionist_profile[work]" id="nutritionist_profile_work" /></div>
<div class="form-group integer optional nutritionist_profile_experience_years"><label class="form-control-label integer optional" for="nutritionist_profile_experience_years">Experience years</label><input class="form-control numeric integer optional" type="number" step="1" name="nutritionist_profile[experience_years]" id="nutritionist_profile_experience_years" /></div>
<div class="form-group string optional nutritionist_profile_how_heard"><label class="form-control-label string optional" for="nutritionist_profile_how_heard">How heard</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="nutritionist_profile[how_heard]" id="nutritionist_profile_how_heard" /></div>
<div class="form-group date optional nutritionist_profile_birthday"><label class="form-control-label date optional" for="nutritionist_profile_birthday_3i">Birthday</label><div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center"><select id="nutritionist_profile_birthday_3i" name="nutritionist_profile[birthday(3i)]" class="form-control mx-1 date optional">
```

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: I couldn't find on the simple_forms docs anything about defining the action. Is there any reason for doingit this way? It looks like that if you just do `simple_form_for profile do |f|` it should identify the profile object and try to update it.

Comment: If i delete this action result is the same(

Comment: I could not find create method in your controlller

Comment: @JagdishN I don't need this method :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is `before_action :load_profile` 
you do not need
`@profile = current_user.profile` in `edit` and `update`

and also for

= simple_form_for @profile do |f|

replace with

```
 = simple_form_for(profile, url: user_profiles_path, action: 'update') do |f|
```

and in `edit` view replace

```
= render 'form_for_client', profile: @profile
= render 'form_for_nutritionist', profile: @profile
= render 'form_for_administrator', profile: @profile
```

with

```
= render partial: "form_for_client", locals: { profile: @profile }
= render partial: "form_for_nutritionist", locals: { profile: @profile }
= render partial: "form_for_administrator", locals: { profile: @profile }
```

and replace

```
def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :description, :first_name, :last_name, :nickname,
                                    :how_heard, :birthday, :experience_years)
  end
```

with

```
def profile_params
params.require("#{current_user.type.downcase}_profile").permit(:name, :description, :first_name, :last_name, :nickname,
                                :how_heard, :birthday, :experience_years)
```

end

Comment: Now i get error 'undefined method `nutritionist_profiles_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fa1b12be058>:0x00007fa19c5b3c78>' app/views/user_profiles/_form_for_nutritionist.html.haml:4:in `

Comment: could you show the `form_for_nutritionist` partial and other two partials

Comment: They are almost the same (as in my post) (only some fields are different = f.input :work
        = f.input :experience_years) etc.

Comment: Although they are same you are having issue in ` = simple_form_for(profile, url: user_profiles_path, action: 'update') do |f|` in this syntax so need to verify in that syntax

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post! Issues are here: 'app/views/user_profiles/_form_for_nutritionist.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_user_profiles__form_for_nutritionist_html_haml___313545030931965891_70165943399760'
app/views/user_profiles/edit.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_user_profiles_edit_html_haml___781735388974955296_70165943561180''

Comment: could you host your code in github so that it will be easy to debug

Comment: I changed first line of my 3 forms to '= simple_form_for(profile, url: user_profiles_path) do |f|' and I receive new error on updating my form - "param is missing or the value is empty: profile" (app/controllers/user_profiles_controller.rb:20:in `profile_params'
app/controllers/user_profiles_controller.rb:10:in `update')

Comment: Tried this, at this point I have stucked 'Update' button and in console 'No template found for UserProfilesController#update, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the form is generating a request that tries to use `create` action which you haven't defined in the `UserProfilesController`.

I assume you wanted `update` to be used instead so to debug why this is the case, you can check dev tools from your browser (network tab specifically) and see yourself what is the actual request being made and why.

Feel free to share network tab info / and more details from stacktrace if you're not able to find the cause of this...

EDIT: Seeing your updated html form. 
Your issue is within `simple_form_for` change it to (as others mentioned):

```
= simple_form_for @profile do |f|
...
# or setup the method/action explicitly (see the gem doc https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)
```

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:3000/user_profiles
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin - it's my Header

Comment: @JessieScinor and if you run `rake routes` you will likely see the `POST` route is pointing towards create method where `Put` `Patch` are pointing towards the update route.  If you inspect the form in your browser I assume it is using the post method, you need to change that to put or patch to target update method.  The fastest way would be to look at any update form in your app and just make it match

Comment: @RockwellRice sounds so easy, but I can't figure out what's going on half a day

Comment: @JessieScinor can you share the generated html of your form (not the template but from the source in browser) that you are trying to submit? (I assume you don't have any extra js mingling with the form outside of it)

Comment: How could I attach it here?

Comment: Edit the original question

Answer (score 0):

Since you instantiate the `@profile` variable and not a `profile` variable:

```
def edit
  @profile = current_user.profile
end
```

How about:

```
= simple_form_for @profile do |f|
```

Instead of:

```
= simple_form_for(profile, url: user_profiles_path, action: 'update') do |f|
```

Oh, I also see you're doing:

```
= render 'form_for_client', profile: @profile
```

I'm not sure that it is necessary to pass the `@profile` into the partial as a local (it may already be available in the view context), but if it is necessary, I believe the correct syntax would be:

```
= render 'form_for_client', locals: {profile: @profile}
```

In which case you would likely do:

```
= simple_form_for profile do |f|
```

...since, in your view context, you would now have the `profile` variable (which you passed in as a local) instead of the `@profile` variable (which you instantiated in the controller). But, again, you may not need to pass in the `profile` variable at all if the `@profile` variable is already available (you'll have to fiddle with it and see - it's be a long time ago that I abstracted this all away so I don't have to mess with it any more).

I can't remember, but you may also need to explicitly use the `render partial` syntax:

```
= render partial: 'form_for_client', locals: {profile: @profile}
```

I personally prefer a symbol to a string for a partial name, when possible:

```
= render partial: :form_for_client, locals: {profile: @profile}
```

Also (from the comments), why are you using `resource:` instead of `resources:`? Also, you need to define `resources: nutritionist_profiles` and `resources: administrator_profiles`. Which is exactly what the error is telling you.

BTW, the reason you're getting the 'undefined method 'nutritionist_profiles_path'' error is that, presumably, your `:form_for_nutritionist` looks something like:

```
= simple_form_for profile do |f|
```

...where `profile` is an instance of `Nutritionist` given this logic:

```
- if current_user.instance_of?(Client)
  = render 'form_for_client', profile: @profile
- elsif current_user.instance_of?(Nutritionist)
  = render 'form_for_nutritionist', profile: @profile
- else
  = render 'form_for_administrator', profile: @profile
```

...and `simple_form_for` uses the `class` of `profile` to determine the path which in this case resolves to `nutritionist_profiles_path`.

Comment: Now i get error 'undefined method `nutritionist_profiles_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fa1b12be058>:0x00007fa19c5b3c78>'

Comment: You probably didn't define the route. You would need to add your `routes.rb` file to your question.

Comment: I added it (devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'user_registrations' }
resource :user_profiles )